# LinkedIn show different title of a same post when user logged in and without login

Tags: linkedin

I am facing some weird problem in LinkedIn. I have shared some post on one company page. when I checked this post without log in it show correct title of the post but after logged in the post title is changed. Please guide me. If any body knows what is the problem. I have already used meta tag open graph in Typo3 website Thanks.

`<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the privacy setting for the account?  [LinkedIn Privacy Settings](https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/)

There are many options as how your content is viewed when logged in and logged out.